# How to prevent Jupyter Notebook from cutting output?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I print, for some reason Jupyter cuts some text out of the middle of output ( perhaps to make it more readable), but I need to see it. 
What are the possible solutions? 
Is there any option I can change in Jupyter to prevent if from cutting?
P.S. Sorry can't embed images yet. Use the link, thx.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ux8.jpg)

[image]

```
my_pipeline = make_pipeline(ce.OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True),
                        SimpleImputer(), 
                        XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, 
                                     learning_rate=0.01,
                                     clf__early_stopping_rounds=10,        
                                     clf__eval_set=[(test_X, test_y)],
                                     random_state=45,
                                     verbose=True))

# fitting and predicting
print(my_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y))
predictions = my_pipeline.predict(test_X)
print("Mean Absolute Error : " + str(mean_absolute_error(predictions, 
test_y)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
 steps=[('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(cols=['Neighborhood'], drop_invariant=False,
   handle_unknown='impute', impute_missing=True, return_df=True,
   use_cat_names=True, verbose=0)), ('simpleimputer', SimpleImputer(copy=True, fill_value=None, missing_values=nan, strategy='mean',
   ver...       reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None, silent=True,
   subsample=1, verbose=True))])
```

As you see on the OUTPUT by the "ver..." - it is cut. Thx.